# Find 1 preceded by 0 in a binary vector

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a binary numeric vector composed by `1`'s and `0`'s. I want to find those `1`'s preceded by `0`'s in the numeric vector. So I want to get the positions `5, 9, 12` for the following vector:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)
```

I have tried this way:

```
which(x==0 & x[-1]==1, T)
```

But it gets the 0's followed by 1's, this is the positions 4, 8 and 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this:

```
which(diff(x)==1)+1
#[1]  5  9 12
```

Since its a binary vector, `diff` evaluation will give `1` whenever a `1` is preceded by a `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
which(x & c(FALSE, diff(x) == 1L))
#[1]  5  9 12
```

Note that a more appropriate data type for a binary vector is `logical`.

Answer (score 2):

We can remove the last observation and first one from the vector, check whether it is equal to 0 and 1 respectively

```
which(x[-length(x)]==0 & x[-1]==1) +1
#[1]  5  9 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
which(tail(x, -1) & !head(x, -1)) + 1
#[1]  5  9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also try `lag` from `dplyr`:

```
which(x == 1 & dplyr::lag(x, 1, 1) == 0)
# [1]  5  9 12
```